# $.post() a javascript array to Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery's `post()`, but my servlet doesn't see the array that I'm passing as a parameter.

My javascript looks like this:

```
var myArray = ['1', '2'];
$.post('action.do', {"arrayData":myArray, "mode":"insert"});
```

In my servlet:

```
System.out.println(request.getParameterMap());
```

which outputs:

> {mode=insert}

I've also tried

```
$.post('action.do', {"arrayData[]":myArray, "mode":"insert"});
```

and

```
$.post('action.do', {"arrayData":$(myArray).serializeArray(), "mode":"insert"});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem. I resolved it just by adding brackets to "arrayData" parameter server-side. On client:

```
$.post('action.do', {arrayData:myArray, mode:"insert"});
```

Please, note, on the client-side `arrayData` parameter is without brackets.

On server:

```
String[] arrayData=request.getParameterValues("arrayData[]");
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$.post('action.do', {"arrayData":myArray, "mode":"insert"});
```

and on server

```
String[] arrayData=request.getParameterValues("arrayData");
```

Comment: For this to work, the parameter map would print something like `{mode=insert, arrayData=java.lang.String@3sD39}` or something similar.  The servlet is not receiving the `arrayData` parameter at all, as a string or string array or any other sort of object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I pass json to my servlet, using [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) from [here](http://www.json.org/). In the servlet you can then use [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), or [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to automatically convert you json to an instance of suitable java class autonoumously.

```
var jsonData = $("#myform").toObject();
var strJson = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
$.ajax({
  cache:false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: myUrl,
  data:strJson,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success:  function(data) {            
          //mySuccessHanlder
    }
});
```